# Extract values and dates of especific line of a text file

Tags: batch-file

Each week i will recive 6 or 7 `.txt` files like that bellow:

```
20/06/18 08:18  1   14 (Sucess, no confirmation needed) 00  0   TEST2   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       1   164 000000                                  complete operation  44376390                0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 08:19  1   1 (ok)  00  1   TEST    ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       4   167 000000                                  TRANSACAO APROVED   44376393                0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 08:21  1   2 (ok)  01  0   TEST2   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       4       000000                                  complete operation                  0   0       48                          
20/06/18 08:25  1   14 (Sucess, no confirmation needed) 00  0   TEST2   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0               986     5   168 000000                          41031930        BEGIN OK    44376394                0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 08:31  1   14 (Sucess, no confirmation needed) 01  0   TEST2   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0               986     6   129 000000                          41031931        BEGIN OK    51321421                0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 08:32  1   14 (Sucess, no confirmation needed) 00  0   TEST2   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       6   169 000000                          41031930        BAIXA OK    44376395                0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 08:32  1   14 (Sucess, no confirmation needed) 00  0   TEST2   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       7   170 000000                          41031930        TEST OK 44376396                0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 08:33  1   14 (Sucess, no confirmation needed) 01  0   TEST2   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       7   130 000000                          41031931        BAIXA OK    51321422                0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 08:33  1   14 (Sucess, no confirmation needed) 01  0   TEST2   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       8   131 000000                          41031931        TEST OK 51321423                0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 08:38  1   2 (ok)  00  4   TEST3   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       11      585945                                  complete operation                  0   0       48                          
20/06/18 08:38  1   2 (ok)  00  4   TEST3   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       12      585946                          00000001    000000000001064 SITUACAO DA TEST OK                 0   0       48                          
20/06/18 08:39  1   2 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       10      585946                                  complete operation                  0   0       48                          
20/06/18 08:39  1   2 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   ANOTHERS/ADM    2   0   0                       11      585947                          00000002    000000000001064 SITUACAO DA TEST OK                 0   0       48                          
20/06/18 09:28  1   1 (ok)  01  0   TEST2   VD DEB  1   2   1   1       FOUND DEBITO    986 11,61   13  134 586242  586242  229873              41031931    0010505962400001    APROVED 229873  12              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 09:40  1   1 (ok)  01  1   TEST    ANOTHERS/ADM    0   0   0                       14  135 000000                                                      0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 10:40  1   1 (ok)  01  0   TEST2   VD CRED 3P LOJ  1   1   3   3       FOUND CREDITO   986 154,30  15  136 586244  586244  600109              41031931    0010505962400001    APROVED 600109  19              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 11:32  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 6P LOJ  1   1   3   6       FOUND   986 369,80  17  138 585948  00184281    009989              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   21              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 11:56  1   1 (ok)  01  1   TEST    VD CRED 6P LOJ  1   1   3   6       FOUND   986 103,80  18  139 000761  248937832   071579              DK059325    000000046782664 TRANSACAO APROVED   24              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 12:24  1   1 (ok)  01  0   TEST2   VD DEB  1   2   1   1       FOUND DEBITO    986 9,90    19  140 586246  586246  295898              41031931    0010505962400001    APROVED 295898  26              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 13:48  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 3P LOJ  1   1   3   3       TEST3           986 174,85  23  146 585950  00354147    244207              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   36              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 13:50  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD DEB 3P LOJ   1   2   3   3       FOUND   986 90,79   24  147 585951  00356608    356608              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   37              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 14:44  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 2P LOJ  1   1   3   2       FOUND   986 73,70   26  150 585952  00417993    OCP3EF              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   42              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 14:55  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD DEB  1   2   1           FOUND   986 30,80   27  151 585953  00432024    432024              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   44              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 15:11  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD DEB  1   2   1           FOUND   986 56,80   28  152 585954  00451469    451469              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   48              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 15:16  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 3P LOJ  1   1   3   3       FOUND   986 473,40  29  153 585955  00458420    051473              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   49              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 15:21  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 5P LOJ  1   1   3   5       FOUND   986 89,90   30  154 585956  00464225    210069              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   52              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 15:22  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD DEB 2P LOJ   1   2   3   2       FOUND   986 74,79   31  155 585957  00466243    466243              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   53              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 15:25  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 3P LOJ  1   1   3   3       FOUND   986 51,80   32  156 585958  00469765    R62243              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   54              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 15:28  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 2P LOJ  1   1   3   2       FOUND   986 66,80   33  157 585959  00474327    068082              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   56              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 16:04  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED     1   1   1           FOUND   986 42,60   34  158 585960  00522515    132114              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   63              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 16:19  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD DEB 2P LOJ   1   2   3   2       FOUND   986 54,50   35  159 585961  00543569    543569              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   64              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 16:28  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED     1   1   1           FOUND   986 53,60   36  160 585962  00555871    096895              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   65              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 16:36  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 2P LOJ  1   1   3   2       TEST3           986 135,40  37  161 585963  00567178    645238              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   67              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 17:09  1   3 (manually confirmed)  01  4   TEST3   VD CRED 2P LOJ  1   1   3   2       TEST3           986 43,69   41  165 585964  00615982    043774              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   69              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 17:11  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   ANOTHERS/ADM    0   0   0                       42  166 000000                                  complete operation                  0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
20/06/18 17:47  1   1 (ok)  01  4   TEST3   VD DEB  1   2   0           TEST3           986 48,80   43  167 585965  00682484    164024              00000002    000000000001064 AUTORIZED   73              0   1   CLIENT Windows  48                          
36  AA295617939D4C16073C5AD86919821D101770A4    221163  0
```

They all will have number of lines differents, dates differents and also values differents.

But what i need is simple, i just need a script in `.bat` that find the last line of the `.txt` file (`36  AA295617939D4C16073C5AD86919821D101770A4    221163  0`) and take the value of the third column `221163` and then convert it to USD: `USD 2.211,63`. Then take the date of the first column in the above line `20/06/18` and join with the value.
It have to be like it: `20/06/18  USD 2.211,63`

Ok, so now it will save like `all_files.txt`.
It must do it with all `.txt` files in the folder and save in the same output file. The result will be like it for example:

```
20/06/18  USD 2.211,63
24/06/18  USD 8.289,45
29/06/18  USD 9.211,99
07/07/18  USD 24.653,76
09/07/18  USD 99.701,32
15/08/18  USD 3.291,19
```

I was making somes tries by this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('findstr /i %1 c:\test\*.txt ^| findstr /i %2') do (
  set last_value=%%i
  )
set=!last_value!
for /f %%x in (%date%) do for /f "delims=.txt,  tokens=1" %%i in (%%x.txt) do echo %%x, %%i >> all_files.txt
```

But it is not going how i expected. How can i make it functional?

---

Tried it now:

```
SET SearchFile=test.txt
SET TmpSearchFile=output.txt
SET String=%date%
SET LineNum=3
FINDSTR /B /N "%String%" "%SearchFile%" > "%TmpSearchFile%"
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=2 DELIMS=: " %A IN (`"FINDSTR /B "%LineNum%:%String%" "%TmpSearchFile%""`) DO ECHO %~A %~A`
```

Im going step by step, but the problem is that the script don't recognize `%date%`, how can i take the present word in that line instaed `%date%` ?

---

Just tried sort the output file by dates.

```
REM get first line:
<all_files.txt set /p first=
REM write it to a new file:
>"test.txt" echo %first%
REM sort the rest and append to the new file:
<all_files.txt more +1|sort >>"test.txt"
del /f /s /q all_files.txt >nul 2>nul
```

I simulated putting in one of all `.txt` files the date `03/07/18` and it doesn't sorted in the right sequence.
This is the output file:

```
20/06/18  R$   2.211,63
22/06/18  R$   1.761,63
03/07/18  R$   3.042,21
25/06/18  R$   1.311,57
21/06/18  R$  22.842,88
```

---

@Lotpings Just changed a little your last script, but still not sorting it by date.

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
mode 34,12

Set "OutFile=all_files.txt"
For %%A in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,3" %%T in ('findstr "^" "%%~fA"') do (
       set "USD=         %%U"
       set "LastDate=!ThisDate!"
       set "ThisDate=%%T"
    )
    set "Out=!USD:~0,-5!.!USD:~-5,3!,!USD:~-2,2!"
    set "Out=!Out: .=!"
    >>"%OutFile%" Echo=!LastDate:~0,2!-!LastDate:~3,2!-20!LastDate:~6,2!  USD !OUT:~-10!
)
```

Look the output file:

```
20-06-2018  USD   2.211,63
22-06-2018  USD   1.761,63
03-07-2018  USD   3.042,21
25-06-2018  USD   1.311,57
21-06-2018  USD  22.842,88
```

Just did the same as you showed me, but for me didn't sorted.

Comment: What's the `SCCM` you are using?

Comment: In answer to your question, modify it!

Comment: @aschipfl System Center Configuration Manager that you are talking?

Comment: I'm talking about the command line `SCCM RemoteControl !last_value!` which I don't understand; what's the purpose of it?

Comment: @aschipfl How i said, i was just making some tries. Found this example of the `!last_value!` in another site. I just tried to catch only numbers, in the case the lasts, but i know that i have to especific the place of that numbers. How i said, it was just tries, isn't working.

Comment: Hm... I don't see a seaious attempt to accomplish the task you describe. At first you should read the help of `for /?` and the usage of [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) in particular...

Comment: @aschipfl Tried using `set` to especific a word, worked more or less, but this is the problem.  I can't specifie a word, because it will always change. It mus find the line and column of the current word and take it to the output file. Some ideia of codding to find a especific line?

Comment: @aschipfl Check the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is an interesting task I had to write a script for it too (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0." & rem // (directory containing the text files to process)
set "_MASK=*.txt"  & rem // (file name pattern for the text files to process)
set "_LIST=all_files.txt" & rem // (name or path of the resulting text file)
set "_TEMP=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (name or path to temporary file)
set "_CURR=USD"    & rem // (currency symbol or abbreviation to be returned)
set /A "_LPAD=0"   & rem // (minimal character width of the returned amount)

rem // Apply default values, if applicable:
if not defined _LIST set "_LIST=con"
if defined _CURR set "_CURR=%_CURR% "

rem // Temporarily change to directory containing the text files:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Write output to temporary text file:
    > "%_TEMP%" (
        rem // Resolve path of resulting text file:
        for %%E in ("%_LIST%") do (
            rem // Loop through all text files sorted by ages:
            for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D "%_MASK%"') do (
                rem // Exclude resulting text file if it is in same location:
                if /I not "%%~fF"=="%%~fE" (
                    rem // Initialise variables for date and amount:
                    set "DAT=" & set "VAL=" & set "PRE=" & set "KEY="
                    rem // Iterate through lines of current text file:
                    for /F "usebackq tokens=1,3" %%G in ("%%~F") do (
                        rem // Store certain token (amount if last line):
                        set "VAL=%%H"
                        rem // Delay storage of another token (date):
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        (
                            for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%J in ("!DAT!") do (
                                endlocal
                                set "PRE=%%J/%%K/%%L"
                                rem // Build sortable date format (sort key):
                                if %%L lss 70 (
                                    set "KEY=20%%L/%%K/%%J"
                                ) else (
                                    set "KEY=19%%L/%%K/%%J"
                                )
                            )
                        ) || endlocal
                        set "DAT=%%G"
                    )
                    rem // Check whether date and amount tokens are found:
                    if defined PRE if defined VAL (
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                        rem /* Convert amount to decimal number with digit grouping
                        rem    of thousands in a separate sub-routine: */
                        call :CONV STR "!VAL!" !_LPAD!
                        rem // Return resulting string:
                        echo(!KEY!  !PRE!  !_CURR!!STR!
                        endlocal
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Write output to resulting text file:
    > "%_LIST%" (
        rem // Read sorted temporary text file and split off sort key:
        for /F "tokens=1*" %%K in ('sort "%_TEMP%"') do (
            rem // Return remaining string:
            echo(%%L
        )
    )
    rem // Clean up temporary file:
    del "%_TEMP%"
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B


:CONV  <rtn_string>  <val_amount>  <val_width>
    ::::Sub-routine to convert a pure natural integer number to a fractional number
    ::::with two decimal places and with digits grouped to thousands. If the input
    ::::value contains characters other than decimal digits, it is returned as is.
    ::::PARAMETERS:
    ::::  <rtn_string>  name of variable to receive the resulting output string;
    ::::  <val_amount>  the input value to be converted;
    ::::  <val_width>   minimal character width of the output string; if greater
    ::::                than zero, the output string is padded on the left with
    ::::                spaces to take at least as many characters specified;
    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
    set "#RES=%~1"
    set "AMT=%~2"
    set "WID=%~3"
    rem // Convert width argument to an integer number:
    set /A "WID+=0"
    rem /* Check whether the input value contains characters other than decimal
    rem    digits and skip processing in case: */
    for /F "delims=0123456789 eol=0" %%Z in ("%AMT%") do (
        set "SEP=%AMT%"
        goto :QUIT
    )
    rem // Extract fractional part from input value:
    set "AMT=00%AMT%"
    set "FRA=%AMT:~-2%"
    rem // Remove trailing zeros from integer part:
    for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%AMT:~,-2%") do set "AMT=%%Z"
    if not defined AMT set "AMT=0"
    rem // Do digit grouping to thousands in a loop from right to left:
    set "SEP=."
    :LOOP
    if not "%AMT:~,-3%"=="" (
        set "SEP=.%AMT:~-3%%SEP%"
        set "AMT=%AMT:~,-3%"
        goto :LOOP
    )
    rem // Assemble converted value:
    set "SEP=%AMT%%SEP:~,-1%,%FRA%"
    rem // Pad value to the left with spaces if a positive width is given:
    if %WID% leq  0 goto :QUIT
    if %WID% gtr 24 set "WID=24"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if "!SEP:~,-%WID%!"=="" (
        set "SEP=                        !SEP!"
        set "SEP=!SEP:~-%WID%!"
    )
    endlocal & set "SEP=%SEP%"
    rem // Return (potentially) converted and padded output value:
    :QUIT
    (
        endlocal
        set "%#RES%=%SEP%"
    )
    exit /B
```

The advantages of this script are:

- that it excludes an already existing output file in the target location from being processed;
- that the digit grouping to thousands is not limited to a certain number of input digits;
- that it sorts the entries in the output file by date in ascending order;

Comment: Worked fine and sorted it fine! ;) Only one problem... the result is that: `20/06/18  USD     2,211.63`. The `,` are changed with the `.`. The correct is `20/06/18  USD     2.211,63` But it's an amazing script! Much interersting the explication of each line!

Comment: Just changed a little your script about what i said in the comment above. Feel free to agree or disagree!

Comment: @aschipfl Last seen: Just observed that has 5 spaces between the coin and the value like it: `25/06/18  USD     1.311,57` i just wanted only one spaces to be like it: `25/06/18  USD 1.311,57` . Really searched it all on your sript, and didn't find how to change it. Can you show me please?

Comment: You mean between `USD` and the amount? that's what constant `_LPAD` is for; just set it to `0` instead of `12`; see my edit...

Comment: @aschipfl I don't know if is too late, but i was using your script fine. But i saw it isn't sorting the date. My last output file is in that sequence: `28/06/18, 29/06/18, 26/06/18, 02/07/18, 27/06/18, 30/06/18` How you can see, it's not sorting right the dates. Can you please check it?

Comment: It is never too late... ;-) Is the (last) date in the input text files somehow linked to their last modification or creation date?

Comment: @aschipfl amazing point! Good way! Yes, it can be based on the creation date. Not modification, just creation!

Comment: @aschipfl sorry, i forgot a important point! How i import this file, the creation date will not be the file, but the imported file. I import all the files, so the the creation date will be all the same...i forgot it, i'm sorry. Can't be this way...But if is easier, we can merge a powershell script into the `.bat`...

Comment: Okay... so there is another (final?) edit... it uses a temporary file to accomplish the sorting...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, there is a final edit to do. Just kidding ;) worked perfect. You are amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT  changed to get the date from the 2nd last line**
**EDIT2 changed output date pattern**

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\06\27\SO_51064650.cmd
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "OutFile=all_files.txt"
For %%A in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,3" %%T in ('findstr "^" "%%~fA"') do (
       set "USD=         %%U"
       set "LastDate=!ThisDate!"
       set "ThisDate=%%T"
    )
    set "Out=!USD:~0,-5!.!USD:~-5,3!,!USD:~-2,2!"
    set "Out=!Out: .=!"
        >>"%OutFile%" Echo=20!LastDate:~6,2!-!LastDate:~3,2!-!LastDate:~0,2!  USD !OUT:~-10!
)
```

Sample output with simulated source files USD*.txt:

You'll get output right aligned (and sortable):

```
> sort all_files.txt
2018-06-20  USD   2.211,63
2018-06-24  USD   8.289,45
2018-06-29  USD   9.211,99
2018-07-07  USD  24.653,76
2018-07-09  USD  99.701,32
2018-08-15  USD     291,19
2018-08-15  USD     291,19
2018-08-15  USD   3.291,19
```

Comment: You take the date of the line one, but can't it. Sometimes the 2 firsts lines will don't have date. It must take the date of the penultimate line. The rest is ok. Just another problem...you especified the file `USD.txt`, but i need that do it with all the `.txt` files in the same folder. Or the line number `3` if is easir to especific than the penultimate line

Comment: Changed to your requirement, but understand that [SO] isn't a script writing service. When a solution doesn't fit to 100% it's up to you to fidle with it - and learning a tad more this way.

Comment: Worked fine! "_but understand that Stack Overflow isn't a script writing service_" Yes, i'll try harder another time! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LotPings Please, check my other edit. Just tried sort it by date.

Comment: The only alphabetical sortable date format would be `(yy)yy/MM/dd` or `yyyy-MM-dd` so why not rearrange the date pattern in a similar way as I did with the USD?

Comment: Well, that trying harder didn't last long ;-) See changed answer.

Comment: I did put the most significant entity the year in front intentionally - otherwise you can't sort a date alphabetically (what sort.exe does). But please don't vandalize your question with endless updates. If a question is solved and you have another one, **ask a new question** leave others (and me) the chance to gain more reputation - this is how [SO] works.

Comment: @LotPings Right! Thank you! :)

Comment: @LotPings If you don't matter, i changed the best answer to the cat, not for me, but his answer is full detailed and will help other people. Ok?

Comment: Nevermind,  I gave him an upvote myself. You choose which answer fits your question best. I have a quite compact PowerShell solution exporting to csv in mind if you are interrested.

Comment: @LotPings that sounds interesting! I would like see if you can!

Answer (score 1):

```
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@ECHO OFF

FOR %%f in (*.txt) DO (
    SET PREV_DATE_STAMP=
    SET DATE_STAMP=
    SET AMOUNT=
    FOR /F "tokens=1,3" %%a IN (%%f) DO (
        REM  Keep the two most recent stamps.
        SET "PREV_DATE_STAMP=!DATE_STAMP!"
    SET "DATE_STAMP=%%~a"
        REM  Keep the last amount datum.
        SET "AMOUNT=%%~b"
    )

    REM  Format the amount. This is tricky to do intelligently with CMD.
    SET /A "NUM_AMOUNT=!AMOUNT!"
    REM   -> #########,##
    SET FMT_AMOUNT=!AMOUNT:~0,-2!,!AMOUNT:~-2!
    REM   Add the digit grouping for thousands
    IF !NUM_AMOUNT! GEQ 10000 SET "FMT_AMOUNT=!FMT_AMOUNT:~0,-6!.!FMT_AMOUNT:~-6!"
    REM   Add the digit grouping for millions
    IF !NUM_AMOUNT! GEQ 10000000 SET "FMT_AMOUNT=!FMT_AMOUNT:~0,-10!.!FMT_AMOUNT:~-10!"
    REM   CMD only uses 32-bit integers, so you millions are the largest value you'll ever get (last 2 digits are hundredths)
    SET "FMT_AMOUNT=          !FMT_AMOUNT!"

    @ECHO !PREV_DATE_STAMP!   USD !FMT_AMOUNT:~-12!
)
```

This script does the work you describe. Of what you need, CMD is particularly unskilled at

- formatting numbers
- dealing with decimals
- dealing with varying line formats
- efficiency

It can be done, though, given the simplifying assumptions you've made.

- whitespace delimiters between date and next column
- whitespace delimiters between last record's first four columns
- amount isn't too large (<= 2^29)

**UPDATE**: Added looping over *.txt (and used delayed expansion for variables inside the loop), and incorporated @LotPings's right-alignment idea (+1 for him).

Comment: Ok, but how can i make it read all `.txt` files in the same folder (not only one file) then save all in the same `output.txt` ? It is taking the string of the first line of the date, but it need take the date of the penultimate line.

Comment: @IamnotHere Sorry. I couldn't tell which date you wanted from your example. The dates were all the same. I've updated the code.

Comment: Ok. Worked fine now `21/06/18   USD 2.842,88`. But it taking some random file, not all the files. It need to do it with all `.txt` files in the folder.
Just changed `@ECHO !PREV_DATE_STAMP!   USD !FMT_AMOUNT!
) >test2.txt` for it save in a output file.`

Comment: @IamnotHere Fixed that. Uses `%%f` now.

Comment: Amazing! Wroked fine!

Answer (score 1):

Here a PowerShell solution which presents 4 alternative ways to format the USD column:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\27\SO_51064650.ps1
$InFile  = ".\*.txt"
$OutFile = "all_files.txt"

$DateUSD = ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem $InFile -File -Exclude $OutFile)){
    $Text = (Get-Content $File | Select-Object -Last 2)
    $USD  = [Decimal](($Text[1] -split ' +')[2]/100)
    [PSCustomObject]@{
         Date = ($Text[0] -split ' +')[0]
         USD1 = $USD
         USD2 = "{0,11:C}" -f $USD
         USD3 = "{0,9:N}" -f $USD
         USD4 = "USD {0,9:N}" -f $USD
    }
}
$DateUSD | Sort-Object {[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.Date,'dd/MM/yy',$Null)} |
  ft -auto  | Out-String | Set-Content $OutFile
```

---

- USD1 is formatted as a decimal number (without thousand's separator)
- USD2 is formatted as a currency (my settings are in € )
- USD3 is a number format (with thousand's separator)
- USD4 is a plain text prefixed with `USD`

---

```
> Get-Content .\all_files.txt

Date         USD1 USD2        USD3      USD4
----         ---- ----        ----      ----
20/06/18  2211,63  2.211,63 €  2.211,63 USD  2.211,63
24/06/18  8289,45  8.289,45 €  8.289,45 USD  8.289,45
29/06/18  9211,99  9.211,99 €  9.211,99 USD  9.211,99
07/07/18 24653,76 24.653,76 € 24.653,76 USD 24.653,76
09/07/18 99701,32 99.701,32 € 99.701,32 USD 99.701,32
15/08/18   291,19    291,19 €    291,19 USD    291,19
15/08/18  3291,19  3.291,19 €  3.291,19 USD  3.291,19
15/08/18   291,19    291,19 €    291,19 USD    291,19
```

Comment: It's clean, functional and great! Very interesting! Thanks for it, i was curious! =)